# OnTap Function doesn't work after changing Button to GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector, statefulwidget

I tried to modify my code to make my button decorated using GestureDetector in Stateful widget, from simple ElevatedButton in Stateless widget.
Once button is tapped, onPressed function from an argument should be called. But after modifying my code, onPressed function is not working like Nothing happens whereas the decoration is working. OnTap function seems fired so it's wierd.

Before (Worked):

```dart
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
onPressed: onPressed,
child: Text(
  text,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
));
```

After (Not working):

```dart
class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const ButtonWidget({Key? key, required this.text, required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ButtonWidget> createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  bool _isElevated = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isElevated = !_isElevated; // This works
          widget.onPressed; // This Not work
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        width: 150,
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            boxShadow: _isElevated
                ? [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey[500]!,
                      offset: const Offset(4, 4),
                      blurRadius: 15,
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                    ),
                    const BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      offset: Offset(4, 4),
                      blurRadius: 15,
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                    )
                  ]
                : null),
        child: Center(child: Text(widget.text)),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should execute `onPressed` callback like this:

```dart
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isElevated = !_isElevated;

          widget.onPressed?.call(); // or widget.onPressed();
        });
      },
...
```

Comment: It solved! thanks a lot! I wonder why I needed explicitly to call callback at this time.